# Excel-VBA Macro only runs properly if it was called by a different workbook first

Tags: excel, vba

In short, the macro only works under a specific condition. Let me explain.

I have a macro that aims to extract two types of data from a workbook. Sometimes the target workbook only has one of the datasets, so I wrote the following 'main' macro:

```vb
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub TBT_main()

    'Efficiency options
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    bCalledFromMain = True
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Checking which data exists, function declared elsewhere
    bMADataExists = checkSheetExists("MA Outlets")
    bOIDataExists = checkSheetExists("Intermediaries data")

    '#Scenario selection#
    If bMADataExists = True And bOIDataExists = True Then
        Call ExtractBoth
        Call TimelineBoth
        Call InsertBoth
        
    ElseIf bMADataExists = True And bOIDataExists = False Then
        Call ExtractMA
        Call TimelineMA
        Call InsertMA
        
    ElseIf bMADataExists = False And bOIDataExists = True Then
        Call ExtractOI
        Call TimelineOI
        Call InsertOI
        
    Else
        MsgBox ("Neither Merchant Acquirer nor Online Intermediary data was found, the macro will now terminate." & Chr(10) & "If there definitely is data, please contact XYZ")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Returning options to normal
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

As for the problem, it involves 2 separate workbooks; Workbook A contains both datasets, workbook B only contains the OI data.

If I freshly open Workbook B (only OI data) and call the main sub, it runs ok but fails to insert any of the data. This happens even if I run it a few times, and no errors are given.

If I then open Workbook A (both datasets) and call the main sub on this workbook, it runs perfectly.

However, if I call the main sub on Workbook B (only OI data) after I have called the main sub on Workbook A, it now runs exactly as intended on Workbook B.

The main sub will continue to run perfectly on Workbook B however many times I try, until I fully close Excel. If I re-open only Workbook B and run the main sub, the problem starts from the beginning.

A few things to note:

1. Most variables & arrays are declared at module level as 'Private' to use between subs.
2. The 'extract' and 'insert' subs are declared as Private subs
3. bCalledFromMain is only used at the beginning and end of the 'Timeline' subs so I can run those subs independently for debugging/development. The code is:

```
'Beginning of sub
'These only run if the sub is run on its own
    If bCalledFromMain = True Then
        'Nothing
    Else
        bMADataExists = True
        bOIDataExists = True
        iNumberOfAccountsMA = 5
        iNumberOfAccountsOI = 5
        iNumberOfTaxYears = 5
        bTotalValuesOnly = False
    End If
'######
'End of sub
'This only runs if the sub is run on its own
    If bCalledFromMain = True Then
        'Nothing
    Else
        'Returning options to normal
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    End If
```

I just realised I could avoid the 'Select Case' by putting the sub calls inside the IF query...

I could post the code inside the secondary subs, but it's too much to reasonably ask anyone to go through, and it works perfectly (other than this problem) anyway.

I've tried researching the problem, but the only answers I'm finding so far have to do with .select, which I only use on a single range just so I can do `ActiveWindow.Freezepanes = True`.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why the discrepancy:

Situation #1: Open a fresh test workbook with only OI data, the macro runs ok but doesn't populate any data.

Situation #2: I run the macro on a workbook with both data sets (runs perfectly), then I run the macro again on the OI-only workbook and suddenly it works perfectly.

I can repeat this process however many times I fully close down Excel.

Edit: Posting the secondary subs for the OI data. Not sure which would be the problem, so I'm posting 2. I can see the timeline one works fine.

```vb
Private Sub ExtractOI()

    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Intermediaries Data")
    With sht

        'Checking the # of OI by counting accont ID's
        Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:="Document ID", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        iNumberOfAccountsOI = .Range(rngToFind, rngToFind.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count - 1

        'Limits the # of OI accounts to prevent the macro terminating mid-run with an overload of data. This will only apply to fringe cases anyway
        If iNumberOfAccountsOI > 50 Then iNumberOfAccountsOI = 50

        'Resizing the arrays
        ReDim arrAccountNamesOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI)
        ReDim arrAccountProvidersOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI)
        ReDim arrAccountIDsOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI)
        ReDim arrAccountBankDetailsOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI)
        ReDim arrAccountEmailsOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI)
        ReDim arrAccountAddressOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI)

        'This array contains strings that act as search parameters
        arrAccountDetailsRowLabelsOI(1) = "Current Acc Trading Name"
        arrAccountDetailsRowLabelsOI(2) = "Name Of Intermediary"
        arrAccountDetailsRowLabelsOI(3) = "Document ID"
        arrAccountDetailsRowLabelsOI(4) = "Current Bank Account 1"
        arrAccountDetailsRowLabelsOI(5) = "Current Email Address"
        arrAccountDetailsRowLabelsOI(6) = "Current Acc Trade Addr String"

        'This jagged array is declared for ease of coding when extracting account information
        arrAccountDetailsOI(1) = arrAccountNamesOI
        arrAccountDetailsOI(2) = arrAccountProvidersOI
        arrAccountDetailsOI(3) = arrAccountIDsOI
        arrAccountDetailsOI(4) = arrAccountBankDetailsOI
        arrAccountDetailsOI(5) = arrAccountEmailsOI
        arrAccountDetailsOI(6) = arrAccountAddressOI

        'Extracting the account information
        For i = 1 To iNumberOfAccountsOI
            For j = 1 To 6
                If j = 3 Then 'Account IDs
                    Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:=arrAccountDetailsRowLabelsOI(j), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
                    arrAccountDetailsOI(j)(i) = rngToFind.Offset(, i).Value2 & "-AD"
                ElseIf j = 4 Then 'Bank details
                    Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:=arrAccountDetailsRowLabelsOI(j), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
                    'Places the formatted sort-code on a different line to the account number
                    arrAccountDetailsOI(j)(i) = rngToFind.Offset(, i).Value2 & Chr(10) & Left(rngToFind.Offset(1, i).Value2, 2) & "-" & Mid(rngToFind.Offset(1, i).Value2, 3, 2) & "-" & Right(rngToFind.Offset(1, i).Value2, 2)
                Else
                    Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:=arrAccountDetailsRowLabelsOI(j), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
                    arrAccountDetailsOI(j)(i) = rngToFind.Offset(, i).Value2
                End If
        Next: Next

        'Extracting the addresss & bank account details if the above failed
        For i = 1 To iNumberOfAccountsOI
            For j = 1 To 6
                If j = 3 Then 'Bank details
                    If VBA.Len(arrAccountDetailsOI(j)(i)) < 4 Then
                        Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:="Previous Bank Account 1", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
                        sAlternateAccountNumber = rngToFind.Offset(, i).Value2

                        Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:="Previous Bank Sort Code 1", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
                        sAlternateSortCode = rngToFind.Offset(, i).Value2

                        arrAccountDetailsOI(j)(i) = sAlternateAccountNumber & Chr(10) & sAlternateSortCode
                    End If
                ElseIf j = 6 Then 'Address
                    If VBA.Len(arrAccountDetailsOI(j)(i)) < 4 Then
                        Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:="Previous Acc Trade Addr String", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
                        arrAccountDetailsOI(j)(i) = rngToFind.Offset(, i).Value2
                    End If
                End If
        Next: Next


    End With 'Ending the With statement to interact with the OI account info sht

    'I declare 3D arrays. One for each year, with dimensions: account, month, and values by intermediary & values by trader
    ReDim arrYearOneOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)
    ReDim arrYearTwoOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)
    ReDim arrYearThreeOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)
    ReDim arrYearFourOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)
    ReDim arrYearFiveOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)
    ReDim arrYearSixOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)
    ReDim arrYearSevenOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)
    ReDim arrYearEightOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)
    ReDim arrYearNineOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)
    ReDim arrYearTenOI(iNumberOfAccountsOI - 1, 11, 1)

    'For looping purposes during the data extraction, I'll create a jagged array to contain the above arrays.
    arrOIData(1) = arrYearOneOI
    arrOIData(2) = arrYearTwoOI
    arrOIData(3) = arrYearThreeOI
    arrOIData(4) = arrYearFourOI
    arrOIData(5) = arrYearFiveOI
    arrOIData(6) = arrYearSixOI
    arrOIData(7) = arrYearSevenOI
    arrOIData(8) = arrYearEightOI
    arrOIData(9) = arrYearNineOI
    arrOIData(10) = arrYearTenOI

    'For the sake of looping, I'll create an array to catalogue the years
    ReDim arrYearsOI(0 To 49)

    arrYearsOI(0) = arrAccountOne_Years 'My sub has up to 50, but removed most for the sake of the post
    arrYearsOI(1) = arrAccountTwo_Years
    arrYearsOI(2) = arrAccountThree_Years
    arrYearsOI(3) = arrAccountFour_Years

    'Using each OI in turn to retrieve values
    For a = 1 To iNumberOfAccountsOI
        Set sht = wb.Worksheets(arrAccountDetailsOI(3)(a))
        With sht 'Closing much further down, right above "Next a"

            'Counts the rows of data, for easy looping later
            Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:="month", SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            iRowCountOI = .Range(rngToFind, rngToFind.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count '#

            'To count the total number of years present
            iCountYears = 0

            'Loops throuh the rows in the OI data, counting how many years there are.
            'Also allocates the different years available to their relevant array
            For Each row In .Range(rngToFind.Offset(1, 0), rngToFind.End(xlDown)).Rows '#
                If IsNumeric(row) Then 'The column has numeric values as years, and text values as months (SEP)
                                       'By counting the cells with a number, we count how many years of data are present
                    iCountYears = iCountYears + 1
                    arrYearsOI(a - 1)(iCountYears) = row
                End If
            Next row

            'Typically there is a breakdown in the OI between "values process by intermediary" and "values process by trader"
            'In case of no breakdown, we're going to set the offset value for "Total_Value"v column
            Set rngTotalValueColumn = .Cells.Find(what:="Total_Value", SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            iTotalValueColumnOffset = .Range(rngToFind, rngTotalValueColumn).Columns.Count - 1 '#

            'This finds the columns for the breakdown described immediately above

            Set rngByIntColumn = .Cells.Find(what:="Value_Process_by_Int", SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            Set rngByTrdColumn = .Cells.Find(what:="Value_Process_by_Trd", SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

            'Now we begin the extraction
            y = 1

            If rngByIntColumn Is Nothing Or rngByTrdColumn Is Nothing Then
                bTotalValuesOnly = True

                For Each row In .Range(rngToFind.Offset(1, 0), rngToFind.End(xlDown)).Rows '#
                    j = 1
                    If IsNumeric(row) Then 'Checking for the years, if we find we begin gathering values
                        For i = 1 To 12
                            If row.Offset(j, 0) = arrMonthsMA(i) Then 'Checks the months match, in case there's no data in the first few months
                                arrOIData(y)(a - 1, i - 1, 0) = row.Offset(j, iTotalValueColumnOffset)
                                arrOIData(y)(a - 1, i - 1, 1) = ""
                                j = j + 1
                            End If
                        Next i
                        y = y + 1
                    End If
                Next row
            Else
                'Calculates the offset to find the relevant values
                iByIntColumnOffset = .Range(rngToFind, rngByIntColumn).Columns.Count - 1 '#
                iByTrdColumnOffset = .Range(rngToFind, rngByTrdColumn).Columns.Count - 1 '#

                For Each row In .Range(rngToFind.Offset(1, 0), rngToFind.End(xlDown)).Rows '#
                    j = 1
                    If IsNumeric(row) Then
                        For i = 1 To 12
                            If row.Offset(j, 0) = arrMonthsMA(i) Then
                                arrOIData(y)(a - 1, i - 1, 0) = row.Offset(j, iByIntColumnOffset)
                                arrOIData(y)(a - 1, i - 1, 1) = row.Offset(j, iByTrdColumnOffset)
                                j = j + 1
                            End If
                        Next i
                        y = y + 1
                    End If
                Next row
            End If

        End With 'To cancel the With statement for each OI sht
    Next a 'For the loop going through each OI sht

    'We don't have MA data to set a baseline, but we have to set the variables so the following loop can work
    iEarliestYear = 2050 'So even the first check will lower the year
    iLatestYear = 1900 'So even the first check will increase the year

    For i = LBound(arrYearsOI()) To UBound(arrYearsOI()) 'Looping through each account
        For y = LBound(arrYearsOI(i)) To UBound(arrYearsOI(i)) 'Looping through each year in each account
            If VBA.Len(arrYearsOI(i)(y)) = 4 Then
                If arrYearsOI(i)(y) < iEarliestYear Then iEarliestYear = arrYearsOI(i)(y) 'Taking the lowest value
                If arrYearsOI(i)(y) > iLatestYear Then iLatestYear = arrYearsOI(i)(y) 'Higher the highest value
            End If
        Next y
    Next i

    'Checking if any dates are n the range for temporary VAT rates. Period from 15 July 2020 to 31 March 2022
    If iEarliestYear > 2022 Then
        bDateInRange = False
    ElseIf iLatestYear < 2021 Then
        bDateInRange = False
    Else
        bDateInRange = True
    End If

    'Counts the # of tax years
    iNumberOfTaxYears = (iLatestYear - iEarliestYear) + 1
    If iNumberOfTaxYears < 1 Then iNumberOfTaxYears = 1

End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub InsertOI()

    'Redoing efficiency options in case they are turned off
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    'Setting a with statement for efficiency
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("OI timeline")
    With sht
        'Sets the first month of the first year
        dtFirstMonth = "1/4/" & iEarliestYear - 1
        .Range("A10").Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 0, dtFirstMonth)

        'Resetting rngtoFind for ease
        Set rngToFind = .Range("A2")

        'Inserting the OI account details
        For i = 1 To iNumberOfAccountsOI
            For y = 1 To UBound(arrAccountDetailsOI())
                With rngToFind
                    .Offset(y, 1 + (i - 1) * 2).Value2 = arrAccountDetailsOI(y)(i)
                End With
            Next y
        Next i

        'Resetting rngToFind for ease
        Set rngToFind = .Range("A9")

        'Inserting the OI data
        For i = 1 To iNumberOfAccountsOI
            For y = 1 To iNumberOfTaxYears
                For k = 1 To 12
                    With rngToFind.Offset(k, 1 + (i - 1) * 2)
                        If arrYearsOI(i - 1)(y) = iEarliestYear Then
                            .Value2 = arrOIData(y)(i - 1, k - 1, 0)
                            .Offset(, 1).Value2 = arrOIData(y)(i - 1, k - 1, 1)
                        Else
                            iYearOffsetOI = 13 * (arrYearsOI(i - 1)(y) - iEarliestYear)
                            On Error Resume Next
                            With .Offset(iYearOffsetOI, 0)
                                .Value2 = arrOIData(y)(i - 1, k - 1, 0)
                                .Offset(, 1).Value2 = arrOIData(y)(i - 1, k - 1, 1)
                            End With
                            On Error GoTo 0
                        End If
                    End With
                Next k
            Next y
        Next i

        'Removing pesky "." values
        .Cells.Replace what:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole

    End With 'Ends the bigger With statement for the sht
End Sub
```

The checkSheetExists function (copied from elsewhere):

```
Function checkSheetExists(sSheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    checkSheetExists = False
    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
        If sSheetToFind = sht.Name Then
            checkSheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sht
End Function
```

I just added the `wb.` to `wb.worksheets`, but it hasn't made any changes.

Comment: It's the code in the subs that is key - post one of them - possibly the way you are referring to ranges

Comment: @CHill60 I've added the secondary subs. I know you asked for one, but I don't know where the problem lies so took the safe bet of posting both.

Comment: You are relying on `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` and have at least one unqualified `Range` reference.  The symptoms you describe strongly suggest at some point you reference an object you don't expect.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I usually rely on Range instead of .Range when referring to static ranges, but I'll modify. I'm so used to ActiveWorkbook/Sheet that I didn't consider those, I'll specify the actual name for them. I'll make the changes and report back if the issue is solved. Thank you for the pointers :)

Comment: @chrisneilsen I've updated the post with your recommended changes. I've removed any mention of `ActiveSheet`, reduced the mentions of `ActiveWorkbook` to a minimum (the wb name will vary, not sure how else to do it), and qualified all my `Range` to `.Range`. The problem remains :/

Comment: How does `checkSheetExists` know which workbook to check?

Comment: Some debug suggestions: 1) if you don't already, add `Option Explicit` to your module, and correct any errors it identifies

Comment: 2) In all your array `Dim`'s and `Redim`'s specify lower bounds (eg `ReDim arrAccountNamesOI(1 to iNumberOfAccountsOI)`) All unspecified lower bounds will be `0` (unliess you have `Option Base 1`) - probably won't solve your problem, but aids robustness/clarity

Comment: 3) Set up the situation you know fails, and add a break point to the first line you expect to output data but doesn't, and run.  If it doesn't break, then you're not reaching that line of code (figure out why that is and you're on your way to solving it)  If it does break, use a watch to check that the range points to the wb/ws/range you expect, and the array indexes are what you expect, and the array data is what you expect.

Comment: Also, consider creating a Minimal Viable Input Sheet (e.g. 4 rows of data), and step through that *line by line* using the F8 button, and copious amounts of examining variable values at each step.  Try to work out how far it actually gets *before* things go wrong.  However, overall, this looks like one or other of the MA functions (that you haven't posted) currently Sets/Initialises a variable that the OI functions *don't* Set/Initialise, but **do** still try to use.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I have `Option Explicit` and `Option Compare Text` but forgot to include them. I'll look to redeclare my lower bounds, but scared of how that'll break my code until I adjust the values haha.

Comment: @chrisneilsen and @Chronocidal Thank you both! I can only accept one posted answer as correct, but if you both post an answer I will upvote both. The problem indeed was that an array initialised in a different sub wasn't ready for the OI subs, the `arrMonthsMA()` array. I've now declared a new sub `arrMonthsOI()` for the OI subs. I will have to accept @Chris's answer though as I would not have found the problem if it weren't for their tip to add a break line and see if the code breaks. It didn't break when it should have, and I found the problem.m Thank you!!

Comment: @chrisneilsen Maybe the notification didn't go through because I tried to tag 2 users, I'm not sure. If you'd like to offer your comment about break points as an answer I will accept it as the correct answer as that led to the solution.